# modifying dictionary keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

I am trying to dynamically create an n dim object finalObj looking like  this for n=3

```
children = { 'value1' : 'some1' , 'value2' : 'some2' , 'value3' :'some3' }

    item = { 'key1' : 'value1' , 'key2':'value2' , 'key3':'value3' }
```

basically, the resulting object would look like this.

```
 finalObj  =  { parent : { 'some1' : { 'some2' : { 'some3':{} } } } }
```

I am creating an n-depth Object below here.

```
var parent ={} 
var finalObj

function makechildren( children, depth ){  
  if (depth>0){       
    makechildren({children}, depth-1);  
  }
  else
  { finalObj=children 
  console.log('finalObj',finalObj) 

  }
  return finalObj
 }

 Promise.resolve(makechildren(parent,4))
 .then(function(resp){
  console.log("resp is",resp); 
  })
```

This prints:

```
{ "children": { "children": { "children": { "children": {} } } } }
```

Now, how to turn

```
parent.children.children.children
```

with

```
item ={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}
```

into

```
parent.children[ item['key1']].children[ item['key2']].children[ item['key3']]
```

which is essentially

```
parent.children['value1'].children['value2'].children['value3']....
```

I have tried making a copy of the original dictionary and altering the keys with a loop and assigning each parent.children[ item['key1']] to the rest of the multidimensional dictionary but didnt go really far.

```
parent1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parent))
for (i in Object.keys(parent))
{ 
parent1[ item['key'+i] ] = parent.children
}
```

However, iam stuck here on how to complete it this way. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the values in `item`, using each one to get the corresponding value from `children`, and use this as the property for a new object. To make the nested object, use a variable to hold the object at the current depth, which you update each time through the loop.

```js
children = { 'value1' : 'some1' , 'value2' : 'some2' , 'value3' :'some3' };

item = { 'key1' : 'value1' , 'key2':'value2' , 'key3':'value3' };

finalObj = { parent: {} };

var cur = finalObj.parent;
Object.values(item).forEach(val => {
    cur[children[val]] = {};
    cur = cur[children[val]];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalObj));
```

Note that the order of items read from an object is not guaranteed, so there's no assurance that this will nest things in the desired order. You should use an array if you want order to be maintained.